# Unable to 301 redirect in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RedirectMatch ^insights/(.*)\.html\?view=(.*)&p=([0-9]+)&/(.*)$ insights/$1/$2/$3-$4.html [R=301,L]
```

Please help me,why it is not working.

### It is displaying error

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at exlwebtest.cloudapp.net Port 80

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING using `RedirectMatch` directive. Besides your syntax of `RedirectMatch` isn't correct. You're mixing that syntax with `mod_rewrite` syntax.

Use `mod_rewrite` rule. Place this in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=([^&]*)&p=([0-9]+)&/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^insights/(.+?)\.html$ insights/$1/%1/%2-%3.html? [R=301,L]
```

It will be better if you provide examples of URLs you're trying to redirect.

Comment: Hello Anubhava it is Showing "The page isn't redirecting properly". Giving too many redirects.

Comment: no Anubhava it is working but some other rules are not working. Actually i , first redirection and second i am mapping it to it's reffer url. So it gives me redirected url but not mapping with reffer url. Ex . www.xyz.com?view=aa&param=bb -- redirect it to www.xyz.com/aa/bb
Then map www.xyz.com/aa/bb to www.xyz.com?view=aa&param=bb

I am looking to achive this

Comment: Well you haven't posted your other rules so I can't guess that. If you post your rules in question I can probably help you out.

Comment: These are actual rules : 

# redirection
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=([^&]*)&p=([0-9]+)&/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^insights/(.+?)\.html$ insights/$1/%1/%2-%3.html? [R=301,L]

#mapping 
RewriteRule ^insights/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ /insights/$1.html?view=$2&p=$3&/$4 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: No not in comments, code should be posted by editing question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192963/redirection-and-mapping-for-same-page-using-htaccess