# redirection and mapping for same page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

redirection and mapping for same page using htaccess not working

Ex . `www.xyz.com?view=aa&param=bb` -- redirect it to `www.xyz.com/aa/bb`

Then map `www.xyz.com/aa/bb` to

```
www.xyz.com?view=aa&param=bb
```

below is the rules.

## redirection

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=([^&]*)&p=([0-9]+)&/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^insights/(.+?)\.html$ insights/$1/%1/%2-%3.html? [R=301,L]
```

## mapping

```
RewriteRule ^insights/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ /insights/$1.html?view=$2&p=$3&/$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work to what you're trying to do:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /insights/anything.html?view=anything&p=anything&/anything
# To /insights/anything/anything-anything.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/([^.]+)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4-%5.html? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /insights/anything/anything-anything.html
# To /insights/anything.html?view=anything&p=anything&/anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^.]+).html$ /$1/$2.html?view=$3&p=$4&/$5 [L]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` only after you have confirmed the rule is working to avoid your browser from caching wrong redirects.

Comment: Thank You!! Prix it's working. Do you have any reference or any book, so i can do this kind of things myself.

Comment: @user3544922 You can start with this one https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html as for a book http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-Apache-mod_rewrite-Guides/dp/1590595610/

Answer (score 0):

Keep these 2 rules at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?view=([^&]+)&param=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?view=$1&param=$2 [L,QSA]
```